# Formatting as.Date as monthly to merge tables

Tags: r, time, merge, time-series

I have following data, that turned out of a pivot table cast(...):

```
df1

date        x    y
2012-04-28  ...  ...
2012-06-29  ...  ...
2012-08-31  ...  ...
2012-09-30  ...  ...

df2

date        x    y
2012-04-20  ...  ...
2012-06-30  ...  ...
2012-08-30  ...  ...
2012-09-28  ...  ...
```

As you can see, I can't match the table through the index on a monthly basis. It will create NAs for some rows. Therefore, I thought, I could go by month time format only.

Following functions were applied:

```
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date)
df1 <- zoo(df1, df1$date)
index(df1) = as.yearmon(index(df1),"%y-%m")
```

Returns:

```
df1

date               x    y
April 2012       ...  ...
June 2012        ...  ...
August 2012      ...  ...
September 2012   ...  ...
```

However, the final result should be

```
df1

date       x    y
2012-04  ...  ...
2012-06  ...  ...
2012-08  ...  ...
2012-09  ...  ...
```

Can you help me?

Comment: why do you need `zoo` here? any specific reasons?

Comment: To be honest I am little puzzled by all the different packages that are available. I ran into one description that showed how to aggregate daily data to monthly data with zoo, which was just what I needed.

Comment: Is there a better way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just use `format` function which is already in R.

```
df1$data <- format(as.Date(df1$date), "%Y-%m")
```

Comment: Is it then still possible to aggregate values for all columns per month?
 Now I have an index that looks like `2012-04` `2012-04` `2012-04` `2012-06` `2012-08` and I would like to aggregate all values that have an equal index (month).  `apply.monthly(df1, FUN = colSums)` doesn't work anymore here.

Comment: I would create two columns, one with the year and one with the months. That will make the work lot easier. I can format the month column and aggregate with both month and year. I can even use month name as "January, February, ..."

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can get some inspiration in the following.

```
x <- as.Date("2012-04-20")
format(x, format = "%Y-%m")
[1] "2012-04"
```

Answer (score 0):

**merge**

If your aim is to create two zoo objects and merge them by year/month then you don't need to convert the date column into a character column.  Instead, try this:

```
library(zoo)

z1 <- read.zoo(df1, FUN = as.yearmon)
z2 <- read.zoo(df2, FUN = as.yearmon)
z <- merge(z1, z2)
```

giving:

```
> z
         x.z1 y.z1 x.z2 y.z2
Apr 2012    1    2    1    2
Jun 2012    3    4    3    4
Aug 2012    5    6    5    6
Sep 2012    7    8    7    8
```

**aggregate**

To aggregate using `mean` by month try this:

```
by_month <- aggregate(z, cycle, mean)
```

giving the following where the index shows the month number:

```
> by_month
  x.z1 y.z1 x.z2 y.z2
4    1    2    1    2
6    3    4    3    4
8    5    6    5    6
9    7    8    7    8
```

**plot**

We could now plot this using:

```
plot(by_month, type = "h", xlab = "month")
```

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** We assume that the input is:

```
Lines <- "
date        x    y
2012-04-28  1    2
2012-06-29  3    4
2012-08-31  5    6
2012-09-30  7    8"
df1 <- df2 <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```